# Force PowerShell to press any key

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a PowerShell script which calls a batch script(*I can't change the content of the batch script*). The batch script prompts `Press any key to continue...` when it finishes and I have to press a key manually.

An example of the PowerShell script:

```
Start-Process script1.bat -NoNewWindow -Wait #this prompts 'Press any key...'
Start-Process script2.bat -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

How can I force PowerShell to *press any key* so it can continue with the following commands?

Comment: Would think that it's not possible. At the point that the `Press any key...` prompt occurs, all control will be in the called script. Even if it was possible How would you know when it was appropriate to 'press a key'. I'm willing to be proven wrong though

Comment: I would expect that there is an equivalent of the batch  `call script.bat < nul`

Comment: Try `start-process "cmd /c echo; | script1.bat" -nonewwindow -wait`.  That should pipe a newline into the batch script, and maybe fulfill the batch script's `pause`.

Comment: @rojo This line throws `InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException` and I'm still searching for the `:`... However, I created a batch script that calls `call script1.bat < nul`. I can live with that.

Comment: I had the same problem, my resolution was to copy the batch file to a working directory and remove the pause from my copy. It doesn't answer the OPs question but it may be a workable solution.
    (Get-Content "$workingDir\script.bat").replace('@pause', '') | Set-Content "$workingDir\script.bat"

Answer (score -2):

EDIT:

Try using Send Keys: 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731008

Hope this helps

Comment: He wants to automate the click, not ask for another one

Comment: This simulates a key-press but PowerShell still waits the batch file to finish its job.